# Cell value dependant drop downs (simple INDIRECT(CellValue) no good)

Tags: excel, formula, dropdown, named-ranges

I have searched web, but can not find a way to do cell value dependant drop down, when more than one DD depends on same cell value.

Here is simplified version of what I am trying to do:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6lWO.png)

The first dependant drop down in Cell C4 uses =INDIRECT(C2) formula in Data Validation. And works perfect - When C2 = "_A", C4 drop down is named range _A.

What formula I need to use in C5 Data Validation to still give me drop down based on same Cell C2 value, but this time from other Named Ranges?

Hope my question makes sense. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need are different string to be inputted in each `INDIRECT` statement.

This can be done with a `VLOOKUP`

First you will need a table matching each possible value in `C2` to named ranges for each cell that will use data validation.

I don't know what your setup is, so I assumed `C2` can only have one of two values: `_A` and `_B` -- just add rows for more values

[image]

In `C4`, use the following formula for Data validation:

```
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(C2,O2:P3,2))
```

And in `C5`:

```
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(C2,O2:Q3,3))
```

You can have the lookup table wherever you want, just change the references accordingly, also put in whatever named ranges you have in the correct spot in the lookup table

Comment: Thank you cybernetic.nomad. Took me some time to understand what you meant (me <-- Lvl2 newbie) But have decoded it and it works! Just need to transfer to my actual workbook :) Perfect! Thank You